# CLLocation getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I am getting an Error when trying to access a CLLocation, can you please explain why?

```
CLLocation *currentLocation;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocation *currentLocation;
```

I am geeting feedback for the location from the location manager:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    if (newLocation != nil) {
        currentLocation = newLocation;
        NSLog(@"locationManager: %@", currentLocation);
    }
}
```

> locationManager: <+36.45307493,
>   +28.22220462> +/- 100.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 9/2/11 10:14:58
>   π.μ. GMT+02:00

but when I am trying to access currentLocation from DidSelectAnnotationView i get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

    NSLog(@"current Location: %@", currentLocation);

}
```

can you please explain why I cannot access it?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are not retaining the location. Do it like:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    if (newLocation != nil) {
        self.currentLocation = newLocation; /// The change is here
        NSLog(@"locationManager: %@", currentLocation);
    }
}
```